# Convert function return set into array

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres user-defined function `f_test` with return type as `RETURNS SETOF TYPE1`.
`TYPE1` is a type with around 10 columns.

Inside postgres procedure `P1`, I want to store the output of `f_test` into an array variable.

I tried the below code to do the same inside the procedure P1.

```
v_array := array_agg(f_test());
```

But I get the below error due to this statement.

```
%aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
```

I also tried the below code

```
v_array := array_agg(row(f_test()));
```

which returns the same error too.

How can I store the result set of `f_test` into array variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html) method:

```
select  
  array_agg(f_test)
into 
  v_array
from 
  f_test();
```

You can also use assignment operator:

```
v_array := (select array_agg(f_test) from f_test());
```